# Using "will" or "would" when we do not know the reality

Tags: grammar

If I do not know about something and I just guess about it what verb should be used "will" or "would"? For example in the following sentences I do not know the reality I just guess, so what verb should be used??

1. The woman sitting next to the man **will/would** be his wife.
2. My friend works in a big company, his salary **will/would** be more than 5000 dollars.
3. My friend is in love with a girl, he **will/would** marry her.
4. The man, who is wearing a white coat, **will/would** be a doctor.

Comment: If you're just guessing, shouldn't you use ***should***? (Although I guess that doesn't work with 3, because it'll get confused with the *ought to* meaning of *should*.)

Answer (score -2):

Your sentences modified  **to express uncertainty** by using correct **subjunctive mood** forms:

***I assume*** that he woman sitting next to the man **/should be/must be/** his wife.

*My friend works in a big company. **I /think/guess/assume/** his salary **might be** more than 5000 dollars.*

*My friend is in love with a girl.  **There's a chance he might** marry her.*

***I guess*** the man wearing a white coat **/must be/should be/** a doctor.

Answer (score -4):

The solution to your question lies in **tense agreement**. Remember that there must be [verb-tense agreement](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/601/04/) and consistency in using the tense. You should avoid mixing tenses as far as possible.

Thus, using this guideline, the sentences can be restructured as:

```
The woman who sat next to the man would be his wife.

My friend works in a big company, hence, his salary is likely more than 5000 dollars.

The man, who is wearing a white coat, is a doctor.
```

Comment: Note that *hence* is not a conjunction, but rather a conjunctive adverb, and so must have a semicolon or period before it instead of a comma.

Comment: ah yes, i know that, forgot in the haste to post :P